# Capture output (sdout/stderr) of SSH port forwarder

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

I would like to store the error below in a variable:

```
ssh -M -S /invalid/path/forwarder.socket -fnNT -Llocalhost:6301:remote_server:22 proxy_server

muxserver_listen bind(): No such file or directory
```

So I tried :

```
result="$(ssh -M -S /invalid/path/forwarder.socket -fnNT -Llocalhost:6301:remote_server:22 proxy_server)"
```

but that leaves bash hanging. I tried `nohup ... &` instead of '-f', with and without '-T', etc. but nothing works.

I known I can use temporary files - `$(...) > file` - but I really prefer an in-memory solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would redirect it to a tmp file.

`ssh -M -S /invalid/path/forwarder.socket -fnNT -Llocalhost:6301:remote_server:22 proxy_server 2> /tmp/tunnel.err 1> /tmp/tunnel.out`

And check that file with `ERROUT=$(cat /tmp/tunnel.err)` and `STDOUT=$(cat /tmp/tunnel.out)`

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that, but I really prefer an 'in-memory' solution. I'll update my question.